# Can't log in to Ubuntu 12.04 "checking battery" flashes up then goes back to login screen

Tags: 12.04, login

I am unable to log into my desktop even though I am using the correct password.  When I type it in and hit enter the screen goes black and was saying something like "checking battery".

I have searched this problem but either I am misunderstanding some of the terminology or it doesn't work. Some threads I have read suggest that lighdm is the problem. I undestand lightdm relates some way to the desktop? 
I have logged in via the terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+f1 but am a bit stuck on what to do from here. I am a relatively new user to Ubuntu and so I am afraid my knowledge of the terminal is poor.

I am not sure what I have done for this error to occur. I was enjoying using Ubuntu instead of windows but this has rather soured the experience.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Rich

I tried `startx` using ctrl+alt+f1 and the following happened:

```
xauth: error in locking authority file /home/richard/.Xauthority 
xauth: error in locking authority file /home/richard/.Xauthority 

Fatal server error: 
Server is already active for display 0 
If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again.

Please consult the X.org foundation support
at http://wiki.x.org for help

ddxSigGiveUp: closing log
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
xlinit: giving up
xlinit: unable to connect to X server: resource temporarily unavailable
xlimit: server error
xauth: error in locking authority file /home/richard/.Xauthority
```

I have had a gander at this website http://wiki.x.org but I don't really understand its relation to me trying to login. Apologies if I'm being dull.

Comment: press  ctrl+alt+f1 and after login type `startx`.

Comment: Thanks guru. Unfortunately that did not work. I did as you advised and the following happened:                                     xauth: error in locking authority file /home/richard/.Xauthority xauth: error in locking authority file /home/richard/.Xauthority Fatal server error:                                               Server is already active for display 0                                      If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these solutions:

From your tty remove the .Xauthority file and also need to remove the .xsession-errors files.

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
sudo rm .xsession-errors*
```

Check the home directory:

```
ls -l /home
```

you may have to give ownership back to your account using chown

```
sudo chown -R username:group /home/username
```

Comment: Hurrah thanks very much Johnny. Problem solved. I did as you instructed. Only thing it said that there was "rm: cannot remove '.Xsession-errors*' : No such file or directory"

Comment: you're welcome! if it suits your need don't forget to accept it. cheers :-)

Comment: that's ok just go with it, sometimes capitalized letter do make sense also :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal by pressing crtl+alt+f1 and type

```
 sudo stop lightdm
 sudo Xorg -configure
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
 sudo start lightdm
```

It should solve your problem.